# neo4j: load2neo not working with arrays

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to use load2neo to read in a graph in Geoff format (which I wrote out using load2neo!).  The extension is installed properly and works with simple queries:

```
$ curl -X POST http://localhost:7474/load2neo/load/geoff -d '(alice)-[:KNOWS]->(bob)'
```

returns:

```
{"alice":70,"bob":69}
```

and

```
$ curl -X POST http://localhost:7474/load2neo/load/geoff -d '(bob)-[:KNOWS]->(carol)'
{"carol":72,"bob":71}
```

Both show up fine in the graph browser.  But when I try to do both at once:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:7474/load2neo/load/geoff -d '[(alice)<-[:KNOWS]->(bob),(bob)-[:KNOWS]->(carol)]'
```

it fails silently.  It also fails silently with:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:7474/load2neo/load/geoff -d @test.geoff
```

with the file contents:

```
[(alice)-[:KNOWS]->(bob),(bob)-[:KNOWS]->(carol)]
```

It's not an authentication problem, I don't think I have the syntax wrong (I've copied it directly from the files that load2neo itself output, and double-checked it against the [spec](http://nigelsmall.com/geoff#spec)), but I just can't figure out why it's not working.  Any ideas?

This is with load2neo 0.6.0 downloaded from the website and Neo4J 2.3.1, community edition.

Comment: did you see any exceptions in data/log/console.log or data/graph.db/messages.log ?

Comment: Where do you see the comma in the spec? Can you try without it?

Comment: Nothing in messages.log (don't see log/console.log anywhere...I'm really fuzzy on where the logs are and how to control them on the OS X.)  Re: the comma ... oddly enough, that does work.  It's clearer if I use (a)-[:knows]->(b)(c)-[:KNOWS]->(d); I get two pairs of connected nodes, as expected.  But looking at the files produced by load2neo itself, they have commas just like I used them.  And unless I'm hallucinating, they're in the spec, under the array sections.

Comment: Correction: using curl, dropping the comma works but it requires dropping the outer '[' and ']' brackets too, both of which features are definitely in Geoff files produced by load2neo itself and clearly in the spec.

Comment: @MichaelHunger Would any of you guys be able to help me with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36329475/no-results-from-load2neo-bulk-load-curl-postcomand) problem? Really similar to yours...