# No results from load2neo bulk load -curl POSTcomand

Tags: python, post, curl, neo4j, py2neo

I'm trying to insert a lot of data into my [neo4j](http://neo4j.com/) db. After reading some opinions I've decided to use [load2neo](http://nigelsmall.com/load2neo) to do so.

I've parsed my data in the [geoff](http://nigelsmall.com/geoff) format.
Inserted the line `org.neo4j.server.database.location=/Users/Lucas/Documents/Neo4j/testdb.load2neo=/load2neo` at my database properties file and placed the two .jar files at `/Applications/Neo4j\ Community\ Edition.app/Contents/Resources/app/plugins`

but when I try to run the Bulk Load command line: `curl -X POST http://localhost:7474/load2neo/load/geoff -d` nothing happens.

I run it at the same directory where my geoff file is (which is not the same directory as the server, is that a problem?) and while my server is on at `http://localhost:7474/` but nothing happens.

Can someone point out what am I missing here? It looks like a simple mistake but I can't find where is it. Thanks!

Comment: I think you made a Paste typo by pasting the wrong content in "command line: http://nigelsmall.com/load2neo"

Comment: oh yes, i'll fix it, but i've only made the mistake here, not on the command execution (:

Comment: Gave up on geoff. I'm doing it with the CSV files ):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

However is trying to insert huge amounts of data into Neo4j should go for the .CSV batch method. I've tried a couple of different methods and this was the only one that worked for me.